# How to get "Word" Importance in NLP (TFIDF + Logistic Regression)

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tf-idf

I have a function to get tfidf feature like this:

```
def get_tfidf_features(data, tfidf_vectorizer=None, ngram_range=(1,2)):
    """ Creates tfidf features and returns them as sparse matrix. If no tfidf_vectorizer is given, 
    the function will train one."""

    if tfidf_vectorizer is not None:
        tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(data.Comment_text)
    else:
        # only add words to the vocabulary that appear at least 200 times
        tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=700, ngram_range=ngram_range, stop_words='english')
        tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(data.Comment_text)        

    tfidf = pd.SparseDataFrame(tfidf.toarray()).to_sparse()
    tfidf.applymap(lambda x: round(x, 4))
    tfidf_features = ['tfidf_' + word for word in tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()]
    tfidf.columns = tfidf_features
    data = data.reset_index().join(tfidf).set_index('index')

    return data, tfidf_vectorizer, tfidf_features    

X_train, tfidf_vectorizer, tfidf_features = get_tfidf_features(X_train)
```

I applied a simple logistic regression like this:

```
logit = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, solver='lbfgs', multi_class='ovr')
logit.fit(X_train.loc[:, features].fillna(0), X_train['Hateful_or_not'])
preds = logit.predict(X_test.loc[:, features].fillna(0))
```

I am getting feature importance like this:

```
 logit.coef_
```

But this is giving me feature importance of "columns" not words

Comment: Are you trying to find the hateful level of a word or of a sentence?

Answer (score 3):

`logit.coef_` is indeed giving you the coefficient of each word feature (or bigram). It will return you an array with `len(features)` elements, where the coefficient of the word in the i-th position in `features` will be located in the i-th position of the `logit.coef_` array.

Example:

```
features = ['love','hate','positive','negative']
logit.coef_ = [0.9, -1.2, 0.5, -0.75]
```

The coefficient of 'love' is 0.9, 'hate' is -1.2 etc...

Comment: ohh thanks. Can I also get to know, which words helped the model to predict "Toxic" words and which word helped the model to predict "non-toxic word"